# What Indexes Would Speed this MySQL Statement

Tags: mysql

I need to change the tables I have in my database so I can store more information against a particular item, the `supplier`. I have one table as follows:

**Product** (~285000 rows)

- product_id
- supplier_name
- barcode
- ...

And want to create two more tables:

**Supplier**:

- supplier_id (`UUID`)
- name (*from product table*)
- contact
- ...

**Supplier Product**:

- product_id (*product FK*)
- supplier_id (*supplier FK*)
- delivery option
- ...

The `supplier` table needs be filled with distinct entries from the `supplier_name` in the `product` table. The `supplier_product` table then needs the `UUID` from the `supplier` table.

My SQL so far is:

```
INSERT INTO supplier (name, id)
SELECT DISTINCT(TRIM(supplier)), UUID() FROM product
WHERE supplier_name IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(supplier_name) != ""
AND TRIM(supplier_name) NOT IN (
    SELECT name FROM supplier
);
```

Creates ~4000 rows. Then:

```
INSERT INTO supplier_product (id, supplier_id, product_id, barcode, ...)
SELECT UUID(), s.id, p.product_id, p.barcode, ...
  FROM product p
  INNER JOIN supplier s ON TRIM(p.supplier_name) = s.name
  WHERE s.name IS NOT NULL;
```

The query is currently timing out after 30 seconds. Is there a better way to populate these two tables?

Creating more tables like this is a pattern I've run across frequently so would appreciate some advice if there is a more optimal way.

Comment: Get rid of the TRIM. This makes it impossible to use the index. If the data needs trimming it, trim it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an index on the `name` column in the `supplier` table and am no longer seeing timeouts. I can drop this index after the `INSERT` has run.